# How to infer keys and values of an object from TS literal union type?

Tags: typescript, union-types

i have  two literal union types of strings and want them to be the possible keys and values of an object.

```
export type AlarmKeyword = 'R1' | 'R2';

export type ResourceTypes = 'nktw' | 'rtw' | 'nef' | 'rth' | 'hlf' | 'dlk';
```

The new type looks like this:

```
export type AlarmKeywordObject = {
  [P in AlarmKeyword]: { [T in ResourceTypes]: number };
};
```

But TS now complains about this code:

```
      {
        R1: {
          rtw: 1,
        },
      }
```

> Type '{ rtw: number; }' is missing the following properties from type
> '{ nktw: number; rtw: number; nef: number; rth: number; hlf: number;
> dlk: number; }': nktw, nef, rth, hlf, dlk

How can i ensure, that the keys are optional and not all of them are required?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use question mark `?` to mark that keys are optional:

```
type AlarmKeywordObject = {
    [P in AlarmKeyword]?: { [T in ResourceTypes]?: number }
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggNgQwE4FsDSEQHcD2SAmUAvFAOQBKAjKVAD5nkBMpA3AFBuiRTkQDOOAK5IAxhAAq4fsTIA7ANbAsNeqSRKVciADNNa4AAs9BuLrpl8ceaw5do8ZOky4CAeQBGAKwgjgMgN5sUFAA2gAKUACWsrCIqBjYePgAugD8AFxQ-qHiUTG8AsJikpB8aZmygijuEEhQAL5s9exscBB+AB7pDvHOSR7evjLBgcFjY1SZo+Mz6liZlAA0QTPB9curzRwiOLICbQB0cDgA5gAUHQCUQA)

Comment: Have used TS for years and *did not know you could do that*. Thanks!